# prove that $rp+1$ does not divide $p^p-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebra-precalculus

$p$ is a odd  prime and $r$ is any odd positive integer. prove that $rp+1$ does not divide $p^p-1$ for any $p$ & $r$.

I have expanded $p^p-1$ to

$p^p-1=(p-1)(p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+...+1)$

since $rp+1$ cannot divide $p-1$ we only have to prove that $rp+1$ does not divide $(p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+...+1)$. But I cannot go further.

Comment: you used $p$ also in the exponent. Is this right ?

Comment: yes. it is so. why this confusion created? Any mistake of mine?

Comment: well you say for any r and p...

Comment: Note that $d\mid(p-1)(p^{p-1}+\cdots+1)$ and $d\nmid p-1$ does _not_ imply that $d\mid p^{p-1}+\cdots+1$. For example $6\mid 4\cdot15$ and $6$ is no divisor of $4$, but $6$ doesn't divide $15$ niether.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\newcommand\ord{\mbox{ord}}q$ be a prime divisor of $p^p-1$. If $\ord_q(p)=k$, then $k\mid p$. So either we have $k=1$ and $q\mid p^1-1$ or $k=p$ and $p\mid q-1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. In particular, if $q\mid\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ we have $2p\mid q-1$ because $q$ should be odd. This means every divisor of $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ is $1$ modulo $2p$.

If $r$ is odd and such that $pr+1\mid p^p-1$, this would imply that there exists a divisor of $p-1$ congruent to $pr+1\equiv p+1$ modulo $2p$, because divisors of $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ do not change the value modulo $2p$. However, being $p+1\pmod{2p}$ implies being $\geqslant p+1$, which is clearly impossible for divisors of $p-1$.